# Validating PHP Form Data Using Java Script

Tags: javascript, php

I am validating php form data using java script, but the form send the data without validating. Am I making any mistake in creating this form validation. HTM code is:

```
<form name="form1" action="sendmail.php" onSubmit="return validateform1();" method="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><input id="name" class="w200" name="name" type="text" value="Your Name" onFocus="if(this.value=='Your Name')this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Name'"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input id="cname" class="w200" name="cname" type="text" value="Company Name" onFocus="if(this.value=='Company Name')this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Company Name'"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input class="w200" name="email" type="text" value="Your Email ID" onFocus="if(this.value=='Your Email ID')this,value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Email ID'"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input class="w200" name="mno" type="text" value="Mobile No." onFocus="if(this.value=='Mobile No.')this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Mobile No.'"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input class="w200" name="country" type="text" value="Country" onFocus="if(this.value=='Country')this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Country'"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><textarea class="w200n h60" name="message" cols="23" rows="4" onFocus="if(this.value=='Requirements')this.value=''" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Requirements'">Requirements</textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"><input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

And the java script for this form validation is:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validateform1() {
        if($document.form1.name.value=="") {
            alert("Enter Name");
            return false;
        }

        if($document.form1.cname.value=="") {
            alert("Please enter company name");
            return false;
        }

        if($document.form1.email.value=="") {
            alert("Please enter your email");
            return false;
        }

        if($document.form1.mno.value=="") {
            alert("Please enter your mobile no.");
            return false;
        }

        if($document.form1.country.value=="") {
            alert("Please enter country");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use $ in "$document"

You should use "document" only

This is what you should be try:

```
<script language="javascript">
function validateform1()
{
if(document.form1.name.value=="")
{
alert("Enter Name");
return false;
}
else if(document.form1.cname.value=="")
{
alert("Please enter company name");
return false;
}
else if(document.form1.email.value=="")
{
alert("Please enter your email");
return false;
}
else if(document.form1.mno.value=="")
{
alert("Please enter your mobile no.");
return false;
}
else if(document.form1.country.value=="")
{
alert("Please enter country");
return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

and call the validateform1() on "onSubmit" event of the form.

Answer (score 1):

simply do this for all fields, because you already have the value assigned for the input type as `Your Name`, we need to check if it is either `Your name`  or `null`

`if(document.form1.name.value=="Your Name" || document.form1.name.value=="")`

Answer (score 1):

If none of the conditions trigger and return `false`, you need to `return true;` at the end before your last closing squiggly bracket ( `}` ).

To clarify: I would write the function like this:

```
function validateform1() {
  if(document.form1.name.value=="") {
    alert("Enter Name");
    return false;
  }
  else if(document.form1.cname.value=="") {
    alert("Please enter company name");
    return false;
  }
  else if(document.form1.email.value=="") {
    alert("Please enter your email");
    return false;
  }
  else if(document.form1.mno.value=="") {
    alert("Please enter your mobile no.");
    return false;
  }
  else if(document.form1.country.value=="") {
    alert("Please enter country");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```